# Loader<Cursor> load only selected row + next row

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursorloader, android-loader

In **activity A** I am loading a list with all the values from my table and have set a setOnItemClickListener to start **activity B** and send an **uri** with the selected item's id[**1**] via send data

[**1**]
`Uri currentTestUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TestEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);`

In **activity B** I have my **onCreateLoader** with the projection:

```
String[] projection = {
       TestEntry._ID,
       TestEntry.COLUMN_TEST_ONE,
       TestEntry.COLUMN_TEST_TWO}
```

...with the return statement

```
return new CursorLoader(this,  
    mCurrentTestUri, //Got this from Activity A         
    projection,             
    null,                   
    null,                   
    null);
```

And my **onLoadFinished** looks something like this:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      int oneColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestEntry.COLUMN_TEST_ONE);
      int twoColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestEntry.COLUMN_TEST_TWO);

      String currentOne = cursor.getString(oneColumnIndex);
      String currentTwo = cursor.getString(twoColumnIndex);

      textViewOne.setText(currentOne);
      textViewTwo.setText(currentTwo);
}
```

---

So far so good, now I wish to show values from the next row (right beneath it) but with a different projection (I only need the `_ID` and `COLUMN_TEST_ONE`) and have **onLoadFinished** display COLUMN_TEST_ONE's value in `textViewThree`.

> [values from both rows should be shown at the same time, not one or
>   another]

I can get the ID of the next row from **activity A** with [**2**] and send it as a string via putExtra but that's about all I have so far.

[**2**]

```
String nextItemId = String.valueOf(listView.getItemIdAtPosition(position + 1));
if((position+1) < lListView.getCount()) {
    intent.putExtra("prevID", nextItemId);
}
```

..or I could create a valid URI path with the next row ID and send it as a string from Activity A and convert it to a URI in activity B if needed with:

```
ContentUris.withAppendedId(TestEntry.CONTENT_URI, nextItemId)
```

> **How should I change my *activity B* to load values from the next row**
>   **and the current one onCreate?**

Comment: What does *"at the same time"* mean? Can you perephrase that part?

Comment: @azizbekian my bad, not exactly at the same time (as in literally) but when the activity starts (onCreate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your query:

```
    Uri currentTestUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(TestEntry.CONTENT_URI, id);
```

Here you are specifying, that you want to query **only** rows, that have specific `id`. Any row, which has different `id` won't be returned in the `Cursor`.

Instead, query the table with appropriate selection arguments:

```
    // Load all rows that have id `firstId` or `secondId`
    return new CursorLoader(this,  
        TestEntry.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,             
        TestEntry._ID + "=? OR " + TestEntry._ID + "=?",                   
        new String[] {firstId, secondId},                   
        null);
```

Then you can get the value of `secondId` row following way:

```
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
          ...

          textViewOne.setText(currentOne);
          textViewTwo.setText(currentTwo);

          if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
              int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(TestEntry.COLUMN_TEST_ONE);
              String next = cursor.getString(index);
              // Use `next` as needed, may be passed to next activity via extras
          }
    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! Will be able to award the bounty only tomorrow but here, take a +1 till then!

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Please do not reward bounty immediately, maybe somebody would come up with a better solution. As long as this will stay as a selected answer - the bounty will be rewarded automatically, no worries.